# When add analytics script, wordpress user login not working

Tags: user-access, google-analytics

When i add Google analytics script the below one
https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXX-X″> (with actual container ID) , my user login not functioning well. I checked console, resolved warnings and all.
I tried the way like integrate analytics using tag manager and that case also same problem for user login
Anyone faced this issue? Please help

Answer (score 0):

You should add the analytics code inside `<script>...</script>`  code ginven to you by Analytics immediately before the `</head>` or, if you want to add it in the footer, right before the closing `</body>`.

If you done that, can you please share the full code you try to add? (make sure to remove the tracking number)

Comment: Integrated analytics on google tag manager and added GTM code in header based on management decision. But still issue is same                                                      
****************
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXXXX');</script>

Comment: Can you give us a link where the error occurs?

Comment: http://43o.f42.myftpupload.com/home-rocket-fun-network/  this is my staging site. In this page, login functionality not working fine. Below there is a checkout button is there integrated with wocommerce. That also redirecting to home page instead of checkout, when we include analytics. Now analytics integrated with tag manager and active in staging site